# Magento 2 search weight is not working

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, product-weight

Magento 2.4 version using.

Search weight is not working properly.
My attribute weight settings -

| Attribute name | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| Product name | 10 |
| Short Description | 5 |
| Description | 4 |
| SKU | 3 |
| Weight | 2 |

Suppose four products

Product name 1 is **hello world 1**

Product name 2 is **hello world 2**

Product name 3 is **hello world 3**

Product name 4 is **test product** but **hello world** is in **Description**

According to Magento Docs - **Search Weight to a number from 1 to 10, where 10 has the highest priority. If no value is entered, all attributes default to a search weight of 1.**

When we search **world** it showing all 4 products which is good but their sort is wrong it is showing **test product** in 3rd place.

these showing like like this -

1 - hello world 1

2 - hello world 2

**3 - test product**

4 - hello world 3

**It should be showing like this -**

1 - hello world 1

2 - hello world 2

3 - hello world 3

**4 - test product**

Anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: Did you have any progress with this problem? I am seeing similar behavior on a site.

Comment: @EliacimDAVILA-CENSERE still i did not found any solution